# Spring Security AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Good evening!

Faced the problem of Spring Security:
[Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthenticationManager' type found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMUxk.png)

Should I override this method in WebSecurityConfig and mark it as @Bean? If so, could you explain how to do this?

I'm using Java Config.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't want to override that method unless you have custom authentication manager. Override two configure methods in Config class,

```
 public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder)
              throws Exception {
          builder.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
      }
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
    }
```